# Pandas calculated columns not updated for new dynamically added rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have an empty pandas dataframe with pre-generated index columns based on datetimeIndex. I also have 2 other columns high and low.

I add a third column and fourth whose value depends on the first two columns i.e high and low

The code snippet is given below

```
header = ['high', 'low']
idx = pd.date_range("09:00", "18:00", freq="60min")
df = pd.DataFrame([],index=idx,columns=header)
df['mv'] = df['high'].ewm(span=3, min_periods=3,
                          adjust=False, ignore_na=False).mean()
df['sum'] = (df['high'] + df['low'])
df.index.name='date'
df.loc[('2018-03-30 09:00:00','high')]  = 106
df.loc[('2018-03-30 09:00:00','low')]  = 100
```

Now If I update the value of the first and second column the values in the third and fourth column continue to be NaN and are not updated.

How to ensure this is done automatically whenever the values in the high and low column changes?

```
def calculate_sum(row):
    print row['high'], row['low']
    return row['high'] + row['low']
df['sum'] = df.apply(calculate_sum, axis=1)
```

As suggested, I changed the df['sum'] row to be handled by a function (code above)

I find that the function is called initially when i assign df['sum']

Any subsequent updates to df['high'] or df['low'] for any rows does not trigger the callback to the function.

Comment: you should def your own function for this

Comment: I added a function but it does not get called on subsequent row updates

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I would define a function that return an updated copy of the dataframe

```
def update_df(tbl, dt, h,l):
    df = tbl.copy()
    df.loc[dt,['high','low']] = (h,l)
    df['mv'] = df['high'].ewm(span=3, min_periods=3,
                          adjust=False, ignore_na=False).mean()
    df['sum'] = (df['high'] + df['low'])
    return df
```

You can update your dataframe:

```
df = update_df(df, '2018-03-30 12:00:00', 50,20)
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same results without creating copies of the dataframe. I want to avoid creating copies as I have hundreds of dataframes and doing this for each and every dataframe is not practical. What I am looking for is some sort of notification or callback when a row is changed so I can use to update the "sum" and "mv" column for that row by performing the calculations.

Comment: you can store the copy on the original dataframe.